# Como calcular columna fecha de nacimiento

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hola estoy empezando en este mundo de scala y spark, estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que extraigo 2 tablas(A y B) y hago join, pero en ese join tengo que calcular una columna llamada "bith_date" a partir de un campo llamado rfc_id, ya hice un reverse para obtener un parte de la fecha,
ejemplo tengo un rfc_id = CGST911222, con el reverse obtengo 911222 y ya solo me queda concatenar 1900 o 2000 según sea el caso, es decir mi resultado seria birth_date= 1991-12-22, esto ya lo hice con sql-spark dejo el ejemplo, pero ahora no se como pasarlo a scala-spark,se que puedo hacer una función para calcular esa columna pero también necesito las demás columnas eso me daría un dataframe con una sola columna , como puedo tener las demás columnas y a la vez calcular mi columna birth_date?

**sql-spark**

```
val cfch = sqlContext.sql("select rfc_id,split,(case when substring(split,1,2) >=(substring(current_date(),3,2))then concat('19',split)else concat(substring(current_date(),1,2),split) end) as concat,customer_id,customer_name, from sp")
```

**scala-spark**

```
val join = A.join(B,
      A.col("customer_id") === B.col("customer_id"), "Inner").
     select(
        A.col("customer_id").alias("customer_id"),
        col("customer_name").alias("customer_name"),
        col("rfc_id").alias("rfc_id"),
        col("homoclave_name").alias("homoclave_name"),
        (reverse(reverse(col("rfc_id")).substr(0,6))).alias("sp_date"),
        col("person_type").alias("person_type"),
        col("identification_sequence_type").alias("person_subclassification_type"),
        col("line_of_business_id").alias("line_of_business_id"),
        col("zipcode_id").alias("zipcode_id"),
        col("town_name").alias("town_name"),
        col("state_id").alias("state_id"))
```

Comment: Podrias poner ejemplos de los dataframes en tu pregunta? Por ejemplo, como en esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806584/trying-to-create-dataframe-with-two-columns-seq-string-spark - Eso seria de ayuda en la busqueda de responderte.